# Error: Cannot find module 'bcryptjs' - Deploying node app to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

I'm trying to deploy my node/express application to heroku and have been running into lots of problems and trying to work through them.  The latest problem is simply `Error: Cannot find module 'bcryptjs'`.  Now I have `bcryptjs` in my `package.json` file, and I've run `npm install` multiple times.  Should I be pushing my `node_modules` folder to heroku as well (it's currently in my `.gitignore`)?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Is package.json in the root of git repository you push to heroku? Do you have package.json in .gitignore, it should not be.

You can push your node_modules directory to heroku, by including it in the git repo, but I don't think this is what most people do.

Comment: No, I don't.  My .gitignore has `.DS_Store, .git-attributes, .sass-cache, data, node_modules`

Comment: But is it actually in the repo. Did you add it?

Comment: Is, it is 100% in the GitHub repo.

Comment: Weird.  no errors on the push to heroku?  And you have something like this in the "dependencies" section of package.json:     "bcryptjs": "~0.7.10",

Comment: No errors on the push to heroku.  I have `"bcrypt": "0.8.0",` in the dependencies section. Oh... maybe it has to be bcryptjs.....

Comment: Gahhhhh... still doesn't work.  It even said on the terminal that it was installing bcryptjs when i pushed to heroku.

Comment: It makes no sense :(.  Where does that Error: Cannot find module   thing happen, do you actually do a require('bcryptjs')

Comment: This should be easy!  Grrrr.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59775/discussion-between-robert-moskal-and-zelliott).